# Seeking advice on runtime error related to uncaught exception of type std::invalid_argument: stoi: no conversion

Tags: c++, exception, c++14

I am writing a test C++ program to find out the difference bits between two numbers.

Header file - code.hpp:

```
#ifndef CODE_HPP
#define CODE_HPP
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<algorithm>
using std::cout;
using std::string;
using std::reverse;
using std::stoi;
using std::endl;

class calcDiffBits{
    public:
    calcDiffBits(int,int);
    ~calcDiffBits();
    private:
    void calc();
    string conv2Bin(int);
    int i;
    int j;
};

calcDiffBits::calcDiffBits(int n, int m):i(n),j(m){
    calc();
}

calcDiffBits::~calcDiffBits(){}

void calcDiffBits::calc(){
    string s1 = conv2Bin(i);
    string s2 = conv2Bin(j);

#ifdef DBG
    cout << "Binary Value of i:" << s1 << endl;
    cout << "Binary Value of j:" << s2 << endl;
#endif

    auto iBin = stoi(s1, nullptr, 2);
    auto jBin = stoi(s2, nullptr, 2);

    auto xorRes = iBin ^ jBin;

    auto diffCount = 0;
    do{
        xorRes >>= 1;
        ++diffCount;
    }while(xorRes);

    cout << i << " and " << j << " differ by " << diffCount << " bits.";
    cout << endl;
}

string calcDiffBits::conv2Bin(int n){
    auto rem = 0;
    string s = "";

    do{
        rem = n % 2;
        s += rem;
    }while(n /= 2);

    reverse(s.begin(), s.end());

    return s;
}
#endif
```

Source file - main.cpp:

```
#include "code.hpp"
using std::cin;

int main(){
    int i, j;

    cout << "Enter the digits:";
    cin >> i >> j;
    calcDiffBits obj(i,j);
    return 0;
}
```

After successfully compiling the code using the following command:

```
g++ -DDBG -ggdb -std=c++14 -Wall main.cpp -o calcDiffBits
```

I found upon running the program that I was getting the following runtime error:

> libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type
>   std::invalid_argument: stoi: no conversion Abort trap: 6

Upon debugging using the debug prints in the code, I could see that the string returned by the function `conv2Bin()` is a null string, because of which the runtime error occurs.

I further debugged the function `conv2Bin()` using GDB and could find that the algorithm adopted inside the function was working as expected. In other words, each time the value in the variable `rem` was getting appended to the `string s`.

So why does the value returned from the function `conv2Bin()` turn out to be a null string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that you add an int to a string, which you later attempt to parse as if it was a valid ASCII representation of a number.

The line in question is

```
s += rem;
```

where `rem` is either `0` or `1`, not `'0'` or `'1'`